# Using "Linq to XML" Try to access multiple element from XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

My attempt to parse XML using **Linq to XML** failed. Despite the fact that as you see ItemList[0] below, I  can get the `ItemList` has many XML element items of the list `ItemList (variable)`, the result shows only one XML element of the `ItemList [0]` in `ItemList (variable)`. I need to print out all elements on the `ItemList [n]`.

**Main Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WPF_ParsingXML.ViewModels.Helper
{
    public class XMLHelper
    {
        public void ParseXML_Sample1()
        {
            // Read a file
            XElement root = XElement.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\..\..\Sample.xml");

            // Assign the default namespace
            XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";

            // Get values from elements
           IEnumerable<XElement> ItemList =
                from el in root.Elements(aw + "PurchaseOrder")
                select el.Element(aw + "Items");
          
            // Print
            foreach (XElement el in ItemList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("###################################");
                Console.WriteLine((string)el.Element(aw + "Item").Element(aw + "ProductName"));
                Console.WriteLine((string)el.Element(aw + "Item").Attribute(aw + "PartNumber"));
                Console.WriteLine("###################################");

            }    
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aw:PurchaseOrders xmlns:aw="http://www.adventure-works.com">
    <aw:PurchaseOrder aw:PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" aw:OrderDate="1999-10-20">
        <aw:Address aw:Type="Shipping">
            <aw:Name>Ellen Adams</aw:Name>
            <aw:Street>123 Maple Street</aw:Street>
            <aw:City>Mill Valley</aw:City>
            <aw:State>CA</aw:State>
            <aw:Zip>10999</aw:Zip>
            <aw:Country>USA</aw:Country>
        </aw:Address>
        <aw:Address aw:Type="Billing">
            <aw:Name>Tai Yee</aw:Name>
            <aw:Street>8 Oak Avenue</aw:Street>
            <aw:City>Old Town</aw:City>
            <aw:State>PA</aw:State>
            <aw:Zip>95819</aw:Zip>
            <aw:Country>USA</aw:Country>
        </aw:Address>
        <aw:DeliveryNotes>Please leave packages in shed by driveway.</aw:DeliveryNotes>
        <aw:Items>
            <aw:Item aw:PartNumber="872-AA">
                <aw:ProductName>Lawnmower</aw:ProductName>
                <aw:Quantity>1</aw:Quantity>
                <aw:USPrice>148.95</aw:USPrice>
                <aw:Comment>Confirm this is electric</aw:Comment>
            </aw:Item>
            <aw:Item aw:PartNumber="926-AA">
                <aw:ProductName>Baby Monitor</aw:ProductName>
                <aw:Quantity>2</aw:Quantity>
                <aw:USPrice>39.98</aw:USPrice>
                <aw:ShipDate>1999-05-21</aw:ShipDate>
            </aw:Item>
        </aw:Items>
    </aw:PurchaseOrder>
    <aw:PurchaseOrder aw:PurchaseOrderNumber="99505" aw:OrderDate="1999-10-22">
        <aw:Address aw:Type="Shipping">
            <aw:Name>Cristian Osorio</aw:Name>
            <aw:Street>456 Main Street</aw:Street>
            <aw:City>Buffalo</aw:City>
            <aw:State>NY</aw:State>
            <aw:Zip>98112</aw:Zip>
            <aw:Country>USA</aw:Country>
        </aw:Address>
        <aw:Address aw:Type="Billing">
            <aw:Name>Cristian Osorio</aw:Name>
            <aw:Street>456 Main Street</aw:Street>
            <aw:City>Buffalo</aw:City>
            <aw:State>NY</aw:State>
            <aw:Zip>98112</aw:Zip>
            <aw:Country>USA</aw:Country>
        </aw:Address>
        <aw:DeliveryNotes>Please notify me before shipping.</aw:DeliveryNotes>
        <aw:Items>
            <aw:Item aw:PartNumber="456-NM">
                <aw:ProductName>Power Supply</aw:ProductName>
                <aw:Quantity>1</aw:Quantity>
                <aw:USPrice>45.99</aw:USPrice>
            </aw:Item>
        </aw:Items>
    </aw:PurchaseOrder>
    <aw:PurchaseOrder aw:PurchaseOrderNumber="99504" aw:OrderDate="1999-10-22">
        <aw:Address aw:Type="Shipping">
            <aw:Name>Jessica Arnold</aw:Name>
            <aw:Street>4055 Madison Ave</aw:Street>
            <aw:City>Seattle</aw:City>
            <aw:State>WA</aw:State>
            <aw:Zip>98112</aw:Zip>
            <aw:Country>USA</aw:Country>
        </aw:Address>
        <aw:Address aw:Type="Billing">
            <aw:Name>Jessica Arnold</aw:Name>
            <aw:Street>4055 Madison Ave</aw:Street>
            <aw:City>Buffalo</aw:City>
            <aw:State>NY</aw:State>
            <aw:Zip>98112</aw:Zip>
            <aw:Country>USA</aw:Country>
        </aw:Address>
        <aw:Items>
            <aw:Item aw:PartNumber="898-AZ">
                <aw:ProductName>Computer Keyboard</aw:ProductName>
                <aw:Quantity>1</aw:Quantity>
                <aw:USPrice>29.99</aw:USPrice>
            </aw:Item>
            <aw:Item aw:PartNumber="898-AM">
                <aw:ProductName>Wireless Mouse</aw:ProductName>
                <aw:Quantity>1</aw:Quantity>
                <aw:USPrice>14.99</aw:USPrice>
            </aw:Item>
        </aw:Items>
    </aw:PurchaseOrder>
</aw:PurchaseOrders>
```

**ItemList[0]**

```
<aw:Items xmlns:aw="http://www.adventure-works.com">
  <aw:Item aw:PartNumber="872-AA">
    <aw:ProductName>Lawnmower</aw:ProductName>
    <aw:Quantity>1</aw:Quantity>
    <aw:USPrice>148.95</aw:USPrice>
    <aw:Comment>Confirm this is electric</aw:Comment>
  </aw:Item>
  <aw:Item aw:PartNumber="926-AA">
    <aw:ProductName>Baby Monitor</aw:ProductName>
    <aw:Quantity>2</aw:Quantity>
    <aw:USPrice>39.98</aw:USPrice>
    <aw:ShipDate>1999-05-21</aw:ShipDate>
  </aw:Item>
</aw:Items>
```

**Result**

```
###################################
Lawnmower
872-AA
###################################
###################################
Power Supply
456-NM
###################################
###################################
Computer Keyboard
898-AZ
###################################
```

**Expected Result**

```
###################################
Lawnmower
872-AA
###################################
###################################
Baby Monitor
926-AA
###################################
Power Supply
456-NM
###################################
###################################
Computer Keyboard
898-AZ
###################################
###################################
Wireless Mouse
898-AM
###################################
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element?view=net-6.0), it says:

> Gets the **first** (in document order) child element with the specified
> XName.

Please notice how it says "first child". In your case you want to retrieve all children, so you need to call [Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=net-6.0#system-xml-linq-xcontainer-elements(system-xml-linq-xname)).

To do that, add a for each loop inside your current one.

```
foreach (XElement el in ItemList)
{
    foreach (XElement elem in el.Elements(aw + "Item")
    {
        // Rest of code left as exercise for reader
    }

}
```

As a side note, look into calling `Descendants` if your only objective is getting the Items nodes.

Answer (score 1):

A better and simpler way.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string filename = @"e:\Temp\Sample.xml";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
    XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";

    foreach (XElement el in xdoc.Descendants(aw + "Item"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("###################################");
        Console.WriteLine(el.Element(aw + "ProductName").Value);
        Console.WriteLine(el.Attribute(aw + "PartNumber").Value);
        Console.WriteLine("###################################");
    }
}
```